# Add 100% Filled image asset in android studio

Tags: android-studio

i am try to add some icon PNG images to android studio as image asset.

but its showing as little transparent. (see image)

how to add image asset as full filled  as image asset in android studio?
any idea?

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCoTF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
     Right click on Res and then click on new then it will display list select Image Asset from the list.Choose your image or clipart from the list and  set as image asset.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: try it, but still have that problem. 
image transparency will decrease after add it as asset. i think problem with white color icons.